# Change text color on mobile width

Tags: wordpress

When the page size reduces to mobile width (using Responsive menu option in Wordpress) my text which overlays a dark image is too dark.  But at full width it's fine.

In pure HTML/CSS I would use a media query to change the text color, but I'm not sure how I can change the font color of a single element in Wordpress, and only with small screen width.

Can someone point out how to do this in Wordpress?

Comment: Just go to __appearance > customize > additional CSS__, and add your media query the same way you would with normal CSS.

Comment: How would I get the ID of the element I wand to modify with CSS?

Comment: Right click and select "Inspect Element"

Answer (score 1):

Go to Appearance -> Customize -> Additional css

Add your media queries

```
@media (max-width: 576px) { 
.....
.....
}
```

Click Publish